# Django - redirect to version with www

Tags: python, django, redirect, dns

Is in Django a simple way to redirect everything from domain without www to version with it? I mean from http:// example.com to http:// www.example.com.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have it. It is PREPEND_WWW in settings.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#prepend-www

Comment: as mentioned by @adamp in the other response, this is actually _very_ buggy and not really recommended, unfortunately: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792064/

Answer (score 11):

As [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware) say

> If PREPEND_WWW is True, URLs that lack a leading “www.” will be redirected to the same URL with a leading “www.”

By default `PREPEND_WWW` is set to `False`. You can change that to True in settings.

```
PREPEND_WWW = True
```

To make this work, You have to include [CommonMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware) in Your middlewares

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: This initially looked like a good solution, but I quickly found various limitations with PREPEND_WWW and went with a solution at the server level. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792064/django-disable-prepend-www-when-using-ip-address-instead-of-domain-name

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. If you have no CommonMiddleware set nothing will happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can also skip prefix via proper DNS configuration.