# django: disable PREPEND_WWW when using ip address instead of domain name

Tags: python, django

Django website running behind load balancer which performs health checks by making an HTTP GET request on /health/ using the instance's IP address rather than the domain name.

I use PREPEND_WWW to add www to the domain name if missing.

But PREPEND_WWW also adds www to the IP address too, which is obviously wrong. e.g. http://www.123.123.123.123/health/

Is there a way to prevent adding the www's for IP addresses, or perhaps only add the www's when a list of regex is matches?

Or should I simply avoid using PREPEND_WWW and implement the redirection manually using a custom view/redirection?

*Please note I am also using SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True, in case that also has implications for the www redirection.*

---

For future reference, I'm using Apache with mod_wsgi on Ubuntu, so my "server level" solution is to use mod_rewrite.

```
# Edit vhost configuration
sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

# Add redirection to VirtualHost block
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.com$1 [R=301,L]
    ...

# Enable mod_rewrite and restart
sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I'd say that this should be done on nginx (or other web server) level in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, `PREPEND_WWW` is a lesser used setting as it is buggy - It does not work properly for host name aliases, ip addresses, or even localhost. 
This is an known issue on Django, and looks like it would not be fixed. 
Here are the details of the [relevant ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5718)

Like @makaveli points out, nginx or any other web server proxy you might be using would be the right place to do the redirection.

However, if you absolutely have to do it in code, here is one way:
One thing you can do is, Write your own [custom middleware which is derived from `CommonMiddleware`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/common.py#L44) which overrides the `process_request`.

For example,

```
must_prepend = settings.PREPEND_WWW and host and not host.startswith('www.')
    redirect_url = ('%s://www.%s' % (request.scheme, host)) if must_prepend else ''
```

Could be (pseudocode)

```
must_prepend = False
ip_address_regex = ....
if settings.PREPEND_WWW:
    must_prepend =  host and not re.match(ip_address_regex, host) and not host.startswith('www.')
redirect_url = ('%s://www.%s' % (request.scheme, host)) if must_prepend else ''
```

And of course, this needs to be well tested out, and it would be your responsibility to update this middleware as the `CommonMiddleware` implementation changes.

Comment: Thanks. I guessed that the python/django solution would be to override process_request and your example is useful to understand how that would work. However, I will follow the recommendation and perform the redirection at the server level.