# Django: Multiple Logins

Tags: django, digital-ocean

I have just deployed my django project on dogitalocean (nginx/ubuntu 16.04) server.

```
In Allowed hosts I added ['.example.com', 'IP']
```

In the DNS records of my digitalocean droplet I added two `A` type records one is pointing `example.com` to the IP, & the second is pointing `www.example.com` to the same IP.

Problem is that I visited the site as `example.com` & logged in as a normal user, & then I opened a new tab (still logged in at `example.com`) & visited site using `www` as `www.example.com` & i'm not logged in there.

How can I redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com`? Thank You :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - redirect to version with www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009884/django-redirect-to-version-with-www)

Answer (score 0):

Your session cookie is not valid for both domains, that's why you're not logged in when accessing `www.example.com`.

One way to fix it is to set

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN=".example.com"
```

in `settings.py` so the session cookie is valid for `example.com` and all subdomains.
(note the `.` preceding the domain name)

See the [Django session settings documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#session-cookie-domain) for more information.